# How do I determine the correct encoding of a csv with pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, character-encoding, character

My file has one value with value which is not recognized by any of the encodings I've tried. The value is `assemblÃ©ia` which means `assembléia` in Portuguese (PT-BR).

I followed some tips of this forum, but didn't work. Follow the tips which I've followed.

```
pd.read_csv(file, encoding= 'utf-8-sig')

pd.read_csv(file, encoding= 'utf8')

pd.read_csv(file, encoding= 'latin-1')
```

None of these encodings worked.

Some idéia ?

Comment: What's the `bytes` value of the string?

Comment: Nit: encoding is making bytes out of a unicode string. Reading bytes from a file to make a unicode string is decoding.

Comment: It seems that the file is not in utf8. There are other encodings, 'iso-8859-1' might work. As noted by Sebastian, having an actual byte string would help to figure this out

Comment: Thanks! how I know the byte's value ? Just to know, the aim Is to back the file, so I'm doing the same stuff on to_csv.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share **result** of `pd.read_csv(file, encoding= <encoding>)` for _all_ used `encoding`… Your pretty vague statement *"None of these encodings worked."* does not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely trying to decode an `UTF-8` encoded document using an ascii-based codec like `latin-1`:

```
>>> "assembléia".encode('utf8')
b'assembl\xc3\xa9ia'

>>> "assembléia".encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'assemblÃ©ia'

>>> "assembléia".encode('utf8').decode('utf-8')
'assembléia'
```

`UTF-8` represents the character `é` as two numbers`\xc3\xa9`. This can be seen in a `UTF-8` [encoding table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

```
U+00E9  é   c3 a9   LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
```

`latin-1` [decodes them as two separate characters](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html):

```
&#195;  *C3*    Ã   &Atilde;    capital A tilde
&#169;  *A9*    ©   &copy;  copyright sign
```

We can replicate your problem:

```
pd.Series(["assembléia"]).to_csv('assembly.csv')
pd.read_csv('assembly.csv',encoding='latin-1')
```

```
    Unnamed: 0  0
0   0   assemblÃ©ia
```

This can be solved by providing `encoding='utf-8'` to `read_csv`:

```
pd.Series(["assembléia"]).to_csv('assembly.csv')
pd.read_csv('assembly.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

```
    Unnamed: 0  0
0   0   assembléia
```

Comment: the main problem  is when I export the file, the word assembléia keeps right in my dataframe but when I export it to csv it back to assemblÃ©ia

import pandas as pd

data = {'Palavra': ['assembléia']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

nome_arquivo_csv = r'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\cv - general\palavra_assembleia.csv'
df.to_csv(nome_arquivo_csv, index=False)